# Should I use std::pmr::vector of pointers or std::pmr::deque of objects?

Tags: c++, vector, iteration, deque

Recently, I asked for a code review of my `Graph` class where I use `std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource` with `std::pmr::vector` of pointers to `Node`s `Edge`s and `Pin`s classes.

```cpp
struct Node;
struct Edge;
struct Pin;

struct Graph {
    //Same approach with ArenaAllocate is used for allocating edges and pins
    Node* AddNode(const std::string_view name) 
    {
        auto node = ArenaAllocate<Node>(*this, name);
        nodes.push_back(node); 
        return node;
    }

    template<typename T, size_t alignment = alignof(T), typename ... Args>
    [[nodiscard]] T* ArenaAllocate(Args&& ... args)
    {
        void* const p = linearArena.allocate(sizeof(T), alignment);
        return p ? new(p) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) : nullptr;
    }

    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource arena{ 1024 * 1024 };
    std::pmr::vector<Node*> nodes{&arena};
    std::pmr::vector<Pin*> pins{&arena};
    std::pmr::vector<Edge*> edges{&arena};
};
```

and the answer was to use `std::pmr::deque` or `std::pmr::list` instead of `std::pmr::vector` to have stable memory addresses and objects instead of pointers.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/281841/266548 -> see the first statement

So I did a quick benchmark. I keep the more/less original `Node` implementation, because its size may be important

```cpp
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

#include <memory_resource>
#include <deque>

struct Node
{
    Node(const std::size_t id, std::string_view name)
        : name(name), id(id)
    {}

    std::vector<std::size_t> inputs{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<std::size_t> outputs{ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    const std::string name;

    std::uint32_t refCount = 0;
    const std::size_t id = 0;
    bool target = false;    
};

static constexpr size_t count = 10000;

static void BM_PMRVectorIterator(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource arena{ 1024 * 1024 };
    std::pmr::vector<Node*> nodes{ &arena };

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        void* const p = arena.allocate(sizeof(Node), alignof(Node));
        auto node = new (p) Node(i, "hello");
        nodes.push_back(node);
    }

    for (auto _ : state) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            nodes[i]->refCount = i;
            nodes[i]->refCount++;
        }
    }
}
BENCHMARK(BM_PMRVectorIterator);

static void BM_PMRDequeIterator(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource arena{ 1024 * 1024 };
    std::pmr::deque<Node> nodes(&arena);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) nodes.emplace_back(i, "Hello");

    for (auto _ : state) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            nodes[i].refCount = i;
            nodes[i].refCount++;
        }
    }
}
BENCHMARK(BM_PMRDequeIterator);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

and iterating over `std::pmr::deque<Node>` is much more slower:

```cpp
---------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                     Time             CPU   Iterations
---------------------------------------------------------------
BM_PMRVectorIterator     131711 ns        92076 ns        11200
BM_PMRDequeIterator     1288377 ns      1293945 ns          640
```

I don't know what to think about it, because both `std::pmr::vector<Node*>` and `std::pmr::deqeue<Node>` don't change much in code usage, but these benchmarks scared me.

The linear allocator should assure that `Node*`s are allocated next to each other, I guess, so there won't be a cache miss.

I want to build a graphical editor for these nodes, pins and edges, so I can't go without iterating over `nodes`, `pins` and `edges`.

What should I do to have a fast and memory-friendly system?

Comment: The operations implied by "*to have stable memory addresses and objects instead of pointers*" and "*iterating over*" are *very different things*. You optimized for stable addresses, but are comparing it to iteration performance.

Comment: Yes, because I'd like to have both. I guess. I'm not sure. I didn't expect that big difference to be honest, because I almost never use `std::deque`

Comment: So, I should stick with `std::pmr::vector<Node*>`?

Comment: You should test accessing a member of `Node` in the timing loops as the locality of a member of `Node` in `std::pmr::vector<Node*>` will be terrible.

Comment: "*Yes, because I'd like to have both.*" I'd like to fly to the moon under my own power; that doesn't mean it's *possible*. Optimization is usually a matter of tradeoffs. "*So, I should stick with `std::pmr::vector<Node*>`?*" That depends on what tradeoffs you're willing to deal with.

Comment: `deque<T>` doesn't have stable address for object, erase can invalidate all of it.

Comment: @appleapple: `erase` in the middle can invalidate them, but not at the ends.

Comment: @RichardCritten I increment a `Node::refCount` variable in both tests. Not sure if it means that it also tests accessing a member of Node.

Comment: @‌NicolBolas true. it's still unstable though.

Comment: Deque may store elements in multiple fixed-size buffers, and chain them together, that could makes the indexing much hard. (Just a guess)